# bounds for nlminb strict or inclusive

Tags: r, optimization

For `stats::nlminb()` are the `lower` and `upper` bounds inclusive?  I read the help page and the examples and all I found were

```
lower, upper: vectors of lower and upper bounds, replicated to be as long as start. 
              If unspecified, all parameters are assumed to be unconstrained.
```

and the example:

```
## 25-dimensional box constrained
## par[24] is *not* at boundary
nlminb(rep(3, 25), flb, lower = rep(2, 25), upper = rep(4, 25))
## trying to use a too small tolerance:
r <- nlminb(rep(3, 25), flb, control = list(rel.tol = 1e-16))
stopifnot(grepl("rel.tol", r$message))
```

I need to know because I have a parameter that cannot be 0 -- that is it can be in the range `(0, Inf)` **NOT** `[0, Inf)`.

Comment: Inclusive, as always in numerical-optimization (by concept). Not being 0 needs awkward things like >= epsilon (hard to tune epsilon). (and i really don't know what to think about asking/answering at the same time...)

Comment: ["To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are, look at this example, where we set the lower bound `lower` to -1 and that is the value `$par` that is returned.

```
> nlminb(start=-0.5,objective=dnorm, lower=-1, upper=0)
$par
[1] -1

$objective
[1] 0.2419707

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 3

$evaluations
function gradient 
       3        3 

$message
[1] "X-convergence (3)"
```

Similarly where the upper bound `upper` set to 1 and that is the value `$par` that is returned.

```
> nlminb(start=0.5,objective=dnorm, lower=0, upper=1)
$par
[1] 1

$objective
[1] 0.2419707

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 3

$evaluations
function gradient 
       3        3 

$message
[1] "X-convergence (3)"
```

More illustrative may be looking at `log()`

```
> nlminb(start=0.5,objective=log, lower=0, upper=1)
$par
[1] 0

$objective
[1] -Inf

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 2

$evaluations
function gradient 
       2        3 

$message
[1] "both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)"
```

If you need your `$objective` to be finite, might need to manually put in a fudge factor for `lower`:

```
> nlminb(start=0.5,objective=log, lower=0+1e-50, upper=1)
$par
[1] 1e-50

$objective
[1] -115.1293

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 2

$evaluations
function gradient 
       2        2 

$message
[1] "both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)"
```